# Optimize multiple SUMIFs addition formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is it possible to optimize below excel formula into simplified one?

```
=SUMIFS(M:M, N:N, "TDAmeritrade", R:R, "Future", E:E, "<>")*0.4 + SUMIFS(M:M, R:R, "Option", A:A,    "SPX", E:E, "<>")*0.4 + SUMIFS(M:M, R:R, "Option", A:A, "VIX", E:E, "<>")*0.4 + SUMIFS(M:M, R:R, "Option", A:A, "RUT", E:E, "<>")*0.4
```

In future, I may have to add more conditions for other symbols like DJX, NDX, NQX, OEX, RUI, XEO, etc, not sure if they can be put into some lookup and then refer into above formula.

First condition has to remain same as its little different and I'm looking for Future value and then rest of the additions need some lookup for each of the above symbols.

Appreciate any help if its possible!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using Excel's `SUMPRODUCT` function along with a table for symbols and their weights.

For example you have a table with symbols and their respective multipliers like this:

| Symbol | Multiplier |
| --- | --- |
| SPX | 0.4 |
| VIX | 0.4 |
| RUT | 0.4 |
| ... | ... |

And let's say this table is located in cells `AA1:AB4`.

```
=SUMIFS(M:M, N:N, "TDAmeritrade", R:R, "Future", E:E, "<>") * 0.4 + SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(M:M, R:R, "Option", A:A, AA2:AA10, E:E, "<>") * VLOOKUP(AA2:AA10, AA$1:AB$4, 2, FALSE))
```

This formula uses `SUMIFS` for the initial condition and then utilizes `SUMPRODUCT` along with `SUMIFS` and `VLOOKUP` to calculate the sum based on the conditions and the multipliers for each symbol.